# Location of view.properties in my project spring mvc jasperreports

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I´m trying to generate reports with jasperreports, acording to documentation I need to configure the ResourceBundleViewResolver like this.

```
<bean id="resourceBundleView" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
    <property name="basename" value="views"/>
</bean>
```

And a file called **view.properties**, the problem is that I don´t know where to place it. Currently, I´m putting it in a folder called views and my file in it. But when I run my controller this error is´s been thrown

**Problem accessing /dwrsimple/reportes/reporteVehiculos.html. Reason:
    Can't find bundle for base name views, locale en_GB**

Hope some one can help me.

Comment: Where you put the file 'views.properties'? if under WEB-INF... try <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/views"/>. I hope it helps you. Saludos!

Comment: Thank you. i found that value="views" it's supposed to be the name of the file, so i renamed my view.properties to views.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. i found that value="views" it's supposed to be the name of the file, so i renamed my **view**.properties to **views**.properties

Answer (score 2):

you have to keep your views.properties under WEB-INF/Classes folder